# Issue looping through dataframes in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dict 'd' set up which is a list of dataframes E.g.:

```
d["DataFrame1"]
```

Will return that dataframe with all its columns:

```
    ID    Name
0  123    John
1  548    Eric
2  184    Sam
3  175    Andy
```

Each dataframe has a column in it called 'Names'. I want to extract this column from each dataframe in the dict and to create a new dataframe consisting of these columns.

```
df_All_Names = pd.DataFrame()

for df in d:
     df_All_Names[df] = df['Names']
```

Returns the error:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Unsure where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example you have df as follow

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['X', 'Y']})
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['X1', 'Y1']})
```

And we create a `dict`

```
d=dict()
d['df']=df
d['df1']=df1
```

Then presetting a empty data frame:

```
yourdf=pd.DataFrame()
```

Using `items` with for loop

```
for key,val in d.items():
    yourdf[key]=val['Name']
```

yield :

```
yourdf
Out[98]: 
  df df1
0  X  X1
1  Y  Y1
```

Comment: I'm not sure I completely follow!

Comment: @CuriousStudent sincey ou have the dict already you just need the last part

Comment: interesting, it seems to be working - going to take my some time to figure out how this works! Thanks

Comment: @CuriousStudent your code tries to use a `DataFrame` as a column name but you actually wanted to use the key from your dictionary i.e. this is what you're doing `df_All_Names[d["DataFrame1"]] = d["DataFrame1"]['Names']` but you want to do this: `df_All_Names["DataFrame1"] = d["DataFrame1"]['Names']`

Comment: I think the OP wants to take the 'Name' column from each dataframe in the dictionary and create a new dataframe independent of the dictionary of dataframes. Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Your can use `reduce` and concatenate all of the columns named `['Name']` in your dictionary of dataframes

Sample Data

```
from functools import reduce
d = {'df1':pd.DataFrame({'ID':[0,1,2],'Name':['John','Sam','Andy']}),'df2':pd.DataFrame({'ID':[3,4,5],'Name':['Jen','Cara','Jess']})}
```

You can stack the data side by side using `axis=1`

```
reduce(lambda x,y:pd.concat([x.Name,y.Name],axis=1),d.values())

   Name  Name
0  John   Jen
1   Sam  Cara
2  Andy  Jess
```

Or on top of one an other using`axis=0`

```
reduce(lambda x,y:pd.concat([x.Name,y.Name],axis=0),d.values())

0    John
1     Sam
2    Andy
0     Jen
1    Cara
2    Jess
```